# Paper js animation of line

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am trying to use paper.js (http://paperjs.org/), below is the running sketch of the code that is drawing an animated line between two points .

http://sketch.paperjs.org/#V/0.12.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

How can i get the same in an html . I tried the below but it is not showing any output .

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8">
                <title>Extruded</title>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="../../dist/paper-full.js"></script>
                <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
                    // Create a path to animate.
                    const path  = new Path();
                    path.strokeColor = 'black';
                    path.add(new Point(0, 0));
                    path.add(new Point(100, 50));
                    
                    // Initialize the time variable that will control the animation.
                    let time = 0;
                    
                    // On each frame...
                    function onFrame() {
                        // ...if the animation is not finished yet...
                        if (time <= 1) {
                            // ...animate.
                            time += 0.01;
                            drawTmpPath(time);
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Initialize the temporary path that will display our animation.
                    let tmpPath;
                    
                    function drawTmpPath(t) {
                        // Make sure that t is never over 1.
                        t = Math.min(t, 1);
                        // Remove the previously drawn temporary path.
                        if (tmpPath) {
                            tmpPath.remove();
                        }
                        // Draw the new temporary path from the reference one.
                        tmpPath = path.clone().set({
                            selected: false,
                            strokeColor: 'orange',
                            strokeWidth: 5
                        });
                        // Split it at the appropriate location.
                        const remainingPath = tmpPath.splitAt(tmpPath.length * t);
                        // Remove the eventual remaining part.
                        if (remainingPath) {
                            remainingPath.remove();
                        }
                    }
                    
                    // Scale things up.
                    project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));
                    
                </script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems to works in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t7vjzrfa/), so I guess that either:

- there is an issue with the loading of the library
- you should load a recent version of [Acorn](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn) before Paper.js in order to support latest JS syntax within Paperscript code (this is the case in Paper.js sketch environment so this could explain your issue)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Extruded</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/acorn"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/paper"></script>
  <script type="text/paperscript" canvas="canvas">
    // Create a path to animate.
    const path = new Path();
    path.strokeColor = 'black';
    path.add(new Point(0, 0));
    path.add(new Point(100, 50));

    // Initialize the time variable that will control the animation.
    let time = 0;

    // On each frame...
    function onFrame() {
      // ...if the animation is not finished yet...
      if (time <= 1) {
        // ...animate.
        time += 0.01;
        drawTmpPath(time);
      }
    }

    // Initialize the temporary path that will display our animation.
    let tmpPath;

    function drawTmpPath(t) {
      // Make sure that t is never over 1.
      t = Math.min(t, 1);
      // Remove the previously drawn temporary path.
      if (tmpPath) {
        tmpPath.remove();
      }
      // Draw the new temporary path from the reference one.
      tmpPath = path.clone().set({
        selected: false,
        strokeColor: 'orange',
        strokeWidth: 5,
      });
      // Split it at the appropriate location.
      const remainingPath = tmpPath.splitAt(tmpPath.length * t);
      // Remove the eventual remaining part.
      if (remainingPath) {
        remainingPath.remove();
      }
    }

    // Scale things up.
    project.activeLayer.fitBounds(view.bounds.scale(0.8));
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```